# ldapsearch - how to filter using ranges for a numeric field

Tags: ldap, openldap

Using ldapsearch v1, where the -E pr=2147483647/noprompt doesn't seem to work. This would have allowed to pull the entire set without slicing it into ranges.

Trying to query ranges of a numeric field.
For example: userid>=300000 & userid<=600000, but this of course uses string comparison and pulls out values that are 3,000,000 or 5,000,000

"?" and "_" wildcards appear not to work in that RFC. I was thinking along the lines of userid=3????? at first.

Is there a trick to make up a filter to make it happen, with "*"s or "Z"s? Can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why `>=` and `<=` are not working for you. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: (userid>=100,000 & userid<=200,000) will pull in 1,000,002 for instance, since the comparison is character-based, instead of pulling in [100,000..200,000] range only.

Comment: it seems like your `userid` attribute stores its numeric values as strings, hence lexicographic comparison is used. I think your only option is to use a truly numeric attribute.

Comment: You need to specify the appopriate `MatchingRuleID` for the attribute, as defined in [RFC 2254](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2254), if you don't want the default matching rule.